# In ReactJS + Flux share a save button with many tabs

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have an strucure in a ReactComponent like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        return (
            <div class="row">
                <MyMenuComponentTab></MyMenuComponentTab>
                <Tab1></Tab1>
                <Tab2></Tab2>
                <Tab3></Tab3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onClick={this.handleButton}>SAVE</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In every tab you can create an independent entity in the backend, and every tab component is related with his own Store and Action in FLUX.

My question is if it's possible to makes the save button contextual? So if you press that button, it can handle in the function "handleButton" Action and Store is related.

The simplest alternative is to have embebed the save button in every tab, but isn't possible because of graphical design restrictions.

Comment: Can you save the currently selected/open tab in your store? If so, you should be able to put your save button anywhere as long as it has access to the store (or if that information is passed to it by a parent component via props).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep track of the active tab in the state of your `MyComponent`. Then, you could pass a callback to each `Tab` that changes the state to reflect which tab is active. That way, your `handleButton` function would only need to access `this.state.activeTab` to handle the save action in context.